# Flutter dart displayName and photoURL is null after linkWithCredential?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Flutter dart displayName and photoURL is null after linkWithCredential? I login thru facebook login.

```
AuthResult result = await _firebaseUser.linkWithCredential(credential);
_firebaseUser = result.user;
print(_firebaseUser.photoUrl); // null
```

i am successfully linked but it doesnt get the profile data
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once there are multiple providers, each of them could have a different photo URL. That why the provider-specific data, and likely the photo URL you're looking for, is in one of the items in the [`UserInfo.providerData` array](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/providerData.html).

Comment: Yup. As far as I can see in the linked documentation, your `result.user` should have a `providerData` property.